# How do I change fill this string through a pointer which points to another pointer which then points to this string

Tags: c, pointers

I'm not sure sure about how I should be doing this. This is my code below. The function readLine reads the line from a file and stores it in string though ptr2. I have a feeling im messing up the stars. Could someone please explain to me what would be the right way to do this.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("testFile.txt","r");

    if( fp == NULL ){
      printf("Error while opening the file.\n");
    }

    char string[75];
    char *ptr1 = &string[0];  //want ptr1 to point to string
    char *ptr2 = &ptr1[0];    //want ptr2 to point to ptr1

    readLine(fp,**ptr2);      //want to send ptr2 pointer so that function read the file and add it to string can be edited through the pointer.
    printf("%s", **string);

    fclose(fp);   
    return 0;
}

readLine(FILE *fp, char **string){
    fgets(**string, 75, fp);
}
```

Edit: I know there are much better ways of doing this. I have done it this way just to help explain the situation i am trying to understand which is how do pass a pointer to a pointer to a function to edit the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `char *p1 = &string[0]`, then you only need to assign the value of `p1` to the `p2`: `char *p2 = p1`.

I think the asterisks are confusing you. If you have an asterisk in variable declaration, like this: `char *p2`, it means that variable `p2` is a pointer, but when you have asterisk in another place, such as `*p2 = 'c'`, the you **dereference** the pointer, that is, you save the value of `'c'` directly to the memory location where `p2` points.

So, here is your code, fixed:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("testFile.txt","r");

    if( fp == NULL ){
      printf("Error while opening the file.\n");
    }

    char string[75];
    char *ptr1 = string;
    char *ptr2 = ptr1;

    readLine(fp, ptr2);
    printf("%s", **pbuff);  // I don't know what pbuff is

    fclose(fp);   
    return 0;
}

readLine(FILE *fp, char *string){
    fgets(string, 75, fp);
}
```

Keep in mind that I didn't compile this because I can't right now, using my sister's computer and she is not a programmer. :)

Comment: No particular reason, just forgot to edit that. :) I will fix my mistake right now. :)

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty you are having, and the question, seems to stem from an unfamiliarity you have with pointers, and how they are passed as parameters to a function. When you declare a character array, e.g. `char string[75];` the value held by `string` is the address to the first character in, (or beginning memory address) for, the statically declared *75-char* array. (it itself is a *pointer*).

When you then declare another pointer to the array, all you need do is assign the value held by `string` (a pointer to the address of `string[0]`) to any new pointer created. e.g.:

```
char *ptr1 = string;
char *ptr2 = ptr1;
```

It is exactly the same as declaring both pointers and then setting them equal to `string`, e.g.:

```
char *ptr1, *ptr2;
ptr1 = ptr2 = string;
```

When you are dealing with pointers, they are nothing more than a *variable* that holds the *address* to something else as their value. Therefore, after the assignment above `ptr1`, `ptr2` and `string` all hold the same value (that being the address to the first character in the *75-char* array).

Now when you pass a pointer as a parameter to a function, the function receives *a copy* of the pointer, just as a function receives a copy of any other variable. This is important. If the pointer is already declared and allocated (either statically or dynamically), you can simply pass a copy of the pointer and the function will still receive its value (the *address* of the array). There is no need to pass the *address of the pointer* in that case, (e.g. `char **`) passing the pointer itself (even though passed as a copy) its *value* still provides the needed *address* of the array.

The only case where you need to pass the address of the pointer are in the cases there the pointer is unallocated (i.e. `NULL` - holding no address), or where the address of the pointer itself is important (i.e. passing a pointer to a *linked-list* where you intend to change the first node in the *list*, etc.) In those cases, then for the calling function to maintain a correct reference to the newly created pointer or the new address for a list (if you delete/add a new first node) -- you must pass the address of the pointer to the function. In your case, that is not required.

In fact, in your case, it doesn't matter which you pass to `readLine` (`ptr1`, `ptr2`, or `string`) as all hold the exact same value -- the beginning address of an allocated array. You are free to read values using either one, as the characters you read will all be stored beginning at the exact same address.

With that in mind, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *readLine (FILE *fp, char *string);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char string[75] = {0};
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char *fn = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "testFile.txt";  /* filename */
    char *ptr1, *ptr2;
    ptr1 = ptr2 = string;

    if (!(fp = fopen (fn, "r"))) {  /* validate file open */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", fn);
        return 1;
    }

    if (readLine (fp, ptr2))
        printf ("%s\n", ptr1);  /* any reference to string will work */
    else
        fprintf (stderr, "error: readLine failure.\n");

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

char *readLine (FILE *fp, char *string)
{
    return fgets (string, 75, fp);
}
```

**Sample Input File**

```
$ cat ../dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/readln ../dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
```

Answer (score -1):

When you declare:

```
char string[80];
```

`string` IS a pointer to the first element in the array of character.

That being said, I don't understand the roles of both `ptr1` and `ptr2`. You can simple use `fscanf` if you want to read into a string.

```
char string[80];
FILE * pFile;

pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt","r");
fscanf (pFile, "%s", string);
```

You'll need to check the return value of `fopen` and `fscanf` of course. Regarding the C function `readline`, it exists in two places `libreadline` and `libedit`. If you are implementing your own `readLine`, it may also have problems.

Addendum: If you want to modify a string inside a function, say `readLine`

```
void readLine(char **arr){
    *arr = "efgh";
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv){
    char *str = "abcd";
    printf("%s\n",str);
    readLine(&str);
    printf("%s\n",str);
    return 0;
}
```

This passess the *address* of the pointer `str` (`readLine(&str)`), and the pointer itself is changed in the function(`*arr = "efgh"`).

Comment: There are no roles for them. I am just using them as examples to help explain what I am trying to find out. I want to know in my situation, how do I send ptr2 as an argument into the function so that the value ofs string can be edited.

Comment: Could you please explain to me how come you use a double star in the function header (**arr)? But when u edit the string you just use *arr = "efgh".

Comment: @Quentin: An array in c is a pointer to the first element in the array.

Comment: @user3886450 no, it's not. Examine the `sizeof` or the `&`adress of an array and a pointer, and you'll see that they are very different indeed.

Comment: @user3886450 It's not the same. Try this: `char s[80]; char *p; s = p;`